# Unable to load the Javascript calendar on Href by using Jquery function 

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have my function as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();
});

function showDate(date) {
//alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
</script>
```

I need this to be called when i click on `Href` tag

```
<a onclick="" href="#">


Metaforce as per you said i tried this 



<script type="text/javascript">
$(function click() {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();
});

function showDate(date) {
    //alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}
    </script>

  <a onclick="return click();" href="#">

    <img alt="cal" src="calendar.gif" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" border="0" /></a>
```

In `onclick` i have to call that how can i any help please

`Patrick Kaufmann and Phillip Kovalev` as per your said i write as follows

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showDate(date) {
  //alert('The date chosen is ' + date);
}

$(function() {
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();

  // assign anonimous function as event handler and call showdate from it 
  $('#clickOnIt').click( function() {
    showDate( $(this).val() );
  } );
});
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <a href="#" id="clickOnIt">click me</a>
```

But i am not getting the desired calendar

Comment: Just for clarity when you describe your function in the first block you are actually demonstrating two function calls, one is an anonymous function called on document ready, the other is a named function that is uncalled. Is it the named function you need to call in the onclick or the anonymous one?

Comment: @Dorababu, please, tell are you using jQuery UI or some other framework? If it's jQuery UI, then use `.datepicker();` instead of `.datepick();` for calendar setup as described in the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#methods) at first.

After that, if you want to show calendar on click by link, use following code for link: `<a onclick="$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepicker('show');">` as described in the [same doc](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#method-show).

Comment: @Phillip : This is the one i am using from [http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html]

Comment: In this case you can use `<a onclick="$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick('show');">` as described in the documentation by you link. Assignment `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();` are right in this case. And StackOverflow isn't the place, there others will read documentation instead of yourself.

Comment: Philip kovalev Thanks a lot if you update your answer i will mark as answer

Comment: @philip another small doubt how can i stop loading calendar when focus is on textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `<a/>` has an unique `id` or `class` attribute you can assign event in your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
  var dateField = $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2');
  dateField.datepick();

  // assign anonimous function as event handler and call showdate from it 
  $('#your_a_selector').click( function() {
    dateField.datepick('show');
  } );
});
</script>
```

Comment: How can i call the function in Href

Comment: Why you are needs to place call in the @href attribute? Assigning function to `click` event has the same result as you wish.

Comment: `<a href="javascript:showDate( $(this).val() );">` is the same, but case in my answer are in right way, because `javascript:` protocol has been deprecated.

Comment: Mmm... your question was _"How to call Jquery function in HREF"_. If you use default `datepicker` component from jquery-ui, right  assign will be `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepicker();` and `$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepicker( "show" );` on the link `click` event. Pls, read the component [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#methods) for more details and ask question by problem subject. Your problem not in the assigning event handler to link, as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Better use the jquery click handler to separate the javascript code from the markup.

Example:

```
<a href="#" id="clickOnIt">click me</a>
```

An then in the javascript file:

```
$('#clickOnIt').click(function() {
    //do the stuff for the click here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
function clickDatePick() {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();
}
```

and add this in onclick: `<a onclick="clickDatePick();" href="#">`

or

```
<a onclick="$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2').datepick();" href="#">
```

Comment: inline events need to die. Besides that, you really want `return false;` in that event handler so the url doesn't get a hash appended which looks annoying and jumps to the top of the page.

Comment: @Dorababu what does the error console tell you? as the @ThiefMaster says, add the return false on the custom "clickDatePick()" function, and then also do the: "return clickDatePick();" in your href...

Comment: can u see my edits in the question as per your answer i changes but it does not work for me

Comment: u're defining the "click" function under the wrong scope, do not define it under any brackets, or any other function... if you know what I mean by that